# SQL Query in Access to prompt with Message Box asking to change table name

Tags: sql, ms-access, onclick, messagebox

Is there a way to be prompted before you a run an SQL query in Access, to enter in the table name that you wish to query? For example, lets say the columns will always stay constant. The columns could be called "Fruit" and "Date." But, the table name could change depending on the batch number. Ie. table name could be "BatchNO_1" or "BatchNO_2" or "BatchNO_3" etc. So Lets say i have an SQL like:

```
select Fruit, Date from BatchNO_1 where Fruit = "Apples"
```

Is there a way that I can be prompted to enter in the table name and have the SQL use the table name i enter to perform the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The table name cannot be passed as parameter to a query. You will have to construct the query yourself.

```vb
Dim tableName as String, sql As String

tableName = InputBox("Please enter the table name")
If tableName <> "" Then
    sql = "SELECT Fruit, Date FROM [" & tableName & "] WHERE Fruit = 'Apples'"
    'TODO: execute the query here
End If
```

For instance, you could change the query text of an existing query like this:

```vb
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myQuery").SQL = sql
```

Or you could execute the query like this

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql)
Do Until rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs!Fruit & " " & rs!Date
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
db.Close: set db = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

By putting the batch number in the table name instead of as a column, you are encoding **data** in the **schema**. This is not best practice, so in my opinion, the correct answer is to change your database design.

Make a single `Batch` table with all the columns from your current `BatchNo` tables, but add a column named `BatchNo` as part of the primary key. Load all the data from your BatchNo tables into this one, and then delete those tables. Then your query will straightforwardly look like this:

```
SELECT Fruit, Date
FROM Batch
WHERE
   Fruit = "Apples"
   AND BatchNo = [Enter Batch No];
```

Don't put data in table names. That is not the way databases are supposed to be made.

Just to explain a little bit, the reason that your current design violates best practice is due to *exactly the problem you are facing now*--the shenanigans and weird things you have to do to work with such a design and try to perform operations in a reasonable, data-driven, way.

By having the user enter the table name, you also create the danger of SQL injection if you aren't also careful to compare the user-provided table name to a whitelist of allowed table names. While this may not be such a big deal in Access, it is still heading down the wrong path and is training for something else besides professional database work. If you would ever like to grow your career, it would be regrettable to first have to unlearn a bunch of stuff before you could even start with a "clean slate" to learn the right way to do things.

Comment: Yes, you are right; however, sometimes the data is generated somewhere else. E.g., each batch could be delivered in a separate CSV file. It can be easier to import the batches into separate tables than importing them into a single table. Personally I prefer to import them into a single table. Especially if the schema becomes more complex, this is a must.

Comment: Whatever the improved ease of importing data into separate tables, the damage this does to the usability of the database simply prevents this from being recommended as a viable solution. Importing to a single table is simply a **must do**.